# Query similar to a where clause in RD

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in Realtime Database:

[image]

I've read a few questions on SO that it's possible and some say it's not possible so I'm a little confused on if this can be done or not but here goes.

I have multiple members (about 200) and I would like to return only those that are mStatus == true.

I attempted it by doing this:

```
const dbRef = ref(db, `organization/${org}/members`);
const queryConstraints = [orderByChild("mStatus"), equalTo("value")]
get(query(dbRef, ...queryConstraints)).then((snapshot) => {
  if(snapshot.exists()) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  } else {
    console.log('No data available');
  }
})
```

The return is null here is the security rule I use:

```
 "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
      "members": {
        ".indexOn": ["mStatus"]
      }
  }
```

How would I run this query?

Comment: In order to run that query, you indeed need to define an index in your security rules. The process is described in the documentation you already linked. If you're struggling to make that work, show the security rules with what you tried and the **complete** error message rather than only part of it.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I dug into this more and read that page using the dinosaurs example I added the security rule (as shown in updated code) does the rule nee to be a full path I got back null @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @AlexMamo see above please

Comment: The `".indexOn": ["mStatus"]` you added creates an index under `members` based on the `mStatus` property of each child node. So that looks good at first glance. Is `members` a node directly under the root of your database?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no sir it's root/organizaiton/{uid}/members/

Comment: You should be getting a warning message that tells you where to add the index in your rules in that case, but I'll also write it up below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the comments you said that your `members` list is under `/organization/{uid}/`, that is also where you have to define the index in your rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "organization": {
      "$uid": {
        "members": {
          ".indexOn": ["mStatus"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```